# Wix custom action method changes not updating installation process

Tags: wix, windows-installer, vsix

How ever made changes into related custom action , also called same method into install sequence at required place , but changes not getting reflected into actual installation process . It always giving me exception at this method . Even I tried to remove this statement from install sequence ,still it giving me exception for same method  .

```
Action ended 6:43:41: InstallFinalize. Return value 1.
MSI (s) (6C:24) [06:43:41:955]: Skipping action: CopyLogFile (condition is false)
MSI (s) (6C:24) [06:43:41:955]: Skipping action: RegisterAspWithIISAction (condition is false)
MSI (s) (6C:24) [06:43:41:955]: Doing action: RemoveVsixTrash
Action 6:43:41: RemoveVsixTrash. 
Action start 6:43:41: RemoveVsixTrash.
MSI (s) (6C:24) [06:43:41:970]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2051) of type 790542 for thread 4132
MSI (s) (6C:D8) [06:43:41:970]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7FE9.tmp, Entrypoint: RemoveVsixTrash
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:064]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2052) of type 790531 for thread 4248
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7FE9.tmp-\
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:126]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2052) of type 790531 for thread 4248
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:173]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2053) of type 790531 for thread 4248
SFXCA: Binding to CLR version v4.0.30319
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:189]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2053) of type 790531 for thread 4248
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:236]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2054) of type 790531 for thread 4248
Calling custom action Allscripts.Automation.CustomAction!Allscripts.Automation.CustomAction.CustomActions.RemoveVsixTrash
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:251]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2054) of type 790531 for thread 4248
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:267]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2055) of type 790531 for thread 4248
Exception thrown by custom action:
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:283]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2055) of type 790531 for thread 4248
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:298]: Creating MSIHANDLE (2056) of type 790531 for thread 4248
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Allscripts.Automation.CustomAction.CustomActions.GetVsVersionInstallDirectories()
   at Allscripts.Automation.CustomAction.CustomActions.RemoveVsixTrash(Session session)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object parameters, Object arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.CustomActionProxy.InvokeCustomAction(Int32 sessionHandle, String entryPoint, IntPtr remotingDelegatePtr)
MSI (s) (6C!98) [06:43:42:298]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2056) of type 790531 for thread 4248
CustomAction RemoveVsixTrash returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
MSI (s) (6C:D8) [06:43:42:345]: Closing MSIHANDLE (2051) of type 790542 for thread 4132
Action ended 6:43:42: RemoveVsixTrash. Return value 3.
Action ended 6:43:42: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

Comment: Have you removed custom action from both InstalExecuteSequence and InstallUISequence?

Comment: Yes . Form both

Comment: Is there any possibility, Any where it takes older version reference to install ?

Comment: If older version exist, it will try to uninstall. You can check msi log for RemoveExistingProducts action.